# Are B-spline basis functions also B-splines?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, spline

When you write a spline curve as a linear combination of b-spline basis functions, it's called a "b-spline".
The basis functions are generated recursively by the deBoor-Cox algorithm, starting with degree zero and working upwards to higher degrees. These b-spline basis functions are thus written in terms of (i.e., as a linear combination of) other b-spline basis functions, so they are also b-splines?

Comment: Usually the basis elements of some vector space are also elements of that vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"B" in b-splines stands for basis.  Unfortunately many people incorrectly refer to other splines (=piecewise-polynomials) as b-splines, and to b-splines as "basis b-splines" or "b-spline basis functions".  Do not become one of those people :)

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. We try to achieve a spline that is a linear combination of b-spline basis functions, right? That spline is called a b-spline. But are the b-spline basis functions also a b-spline?

Comment: No.  A non-trivial linear combination of B (basis) splines is [correctly] called a spline.  The only b-splines are basis splines.  Unfortunately people use incorrect terminology all the time.

Comment: But you can have splines that are not formed based on a linear combination of B (basis) splines, right? Isn't it then wrong to say that they are also "splines", based on your definition?

Comment: Could you give me an example of a spline, that cannot be written as a combination of b-splines?

Comment: What I meant is that they can be written, but they are not. They are written in another way.

Comment: The definition of a spline is that it is a piecewise polynomial.   Any spline can be written as a combination of B-splines.  I am not sure how this can be made more clear.

Comment: So you are saying that this answer from @bubba is wrong? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/700183/744941
"When you write a spline curve as a linear combination of b-spline basis functions in this way, it's called a "b-spline"

Comment: This just proves my point: people use incorrect terminology **all the time**.